# How to use commonJS node module in AMD project?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gulp, amd, r.js

We are using AMD modules in our project. I want to use a 3rd party commonJS module that is installed through npm install. I had a problem which [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922297/why-shim-is-not-working-with-gulp-requirejs-and-working-with-r-js). Hence trying another strategy to use commonJS module in my requireJS build.

So, I am trying to use instructions mentioned [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) to declare my commonJS module in my AMD build. Here I am facing a different problem. Although I see the r.js is able to load node module in gulp process, its not able to load node module when exceuting

```
// NOT WORKING. WHY ??
requirejs.optimize(config, function(buildResponse){
  console.log('build response', buildResponse);
}, cb);
```

Here is my full gulp file :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

config = {
  name: 'src/app',
  baseUrl: ".",
  out: 'dist/app.build.js',
  nodeRequire: require,
  paths: {
      "jquery": "lib/jquery-1.12.0",
      "underscore": "lib/underscore"
  }
};
requirejs.config(config);

gulp.task('requirejs', function (cb) {

// WORKING: r.js is able to load dagre-d3 in commonJS path
console.log('1.5 dagreD3: ' + requirejs('dagre-d3'));


// WORKING: r.js is able to load dagre-d3 in commonJS path
requirejs(['dagre-d3'], function ( dagreD3 ) {
    console.log('2 dagreD3: ' + dagreD3);
});

// NOT WORKING. WHY ??
requirejs.optimize(config, function(buildResponse){
    console.log('build response', buildResponse);
   }, cb);
});


// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
gulp.task('default', ['requirejs']);
```

Here is my [git repo](https://github.com/arun-kahuna/using_commonJS_module_with_amd) illustrating the problem.

Following is the error iam getting while executing gulp:

```
[11:30:55] Starting 'requirejs'...
1.5 dagreD3: [object Object]
[11:30:55] 'requirejs' errored after 339 ms
[11:30:55] Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/dagre-d3.js'
In module tree:
    src/app
    at Error (native)

    at /Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:25150:19
    at /Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3056:39
    at /Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2996:25
    at Function.prim.nextTick (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:24901:9)
    at Object.p.errback (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2995:26)
    at Object.p.callback (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2981:23)
    at Object.p.promise.then (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3035:23)
    at build (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:25107:12)
    at runBuild (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27115:17)
    at Object.context.execCb (/Users/akandregula/arun/amd-practice/using_commonJS_module_with_amd/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1943:33)
2 dagreD3: [object Object]
```